# Imaginary time?

Tags: special-relativity

If we begin with the equation for time dilation:

$$ \Delta t^\prime = \frac{\Delta t}{\sqrt{1-\frac{v^2}{c^2}}} $$

Now, for a particle moving in space with no potential energy,

$$ E = \frac{1}{2} mv^2 $$

So

$$ v^2 = \frac{2E}{m} $$

Then

$$ \Delta t^\prime = \frac{\Delta t}{\sqrt{1-\frac{2E}{mc^2}}} $$

$$ = \frac{\Delta t}{\sqrt{1-2}} $$

$$ = \frac{\Delta t}{\sqrt{-1}} $$

Explain please?

Comment: This $E = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$ is only correct in the limit of $v \ll c$ (the Newtonian or non-relativistic limit). The generally correct expression is $E = \sqrt{(mc^2)^2 + (pc)^2}$. It follows that rest of your work is also incorrect except in that limit. *Never* mix relativistically correct and Newtonian math. Unless you *really* know what you are doing, of course.

Comment: @dmckee that could probably be an answer

Comment: After enough comment edits I'll even get the units right. *::sigh::* That's why particle physicists work in $c = 1$ units: because we're too dumb to handle SI units.

Answer (score 7):

This $E = \frac{1}{2}mv^2$ is only correct in the limit of $v \ll c$ (the Newtonian or non-relativistic limit). The generally correct expression is $$E = \sqrt{(mc^2)^2 + (pc)^2}\,.$$ It follows that rest of your work is also incorrect.

---

*Never* mix relativistically correct and Newtonian math. Unless you *really* know what you are doing, of course.

Comment: Because I've no interest in gaining rep on it.

Answer (score 1):

Generally, $E = \gamma mc^2$ which becomes $E = \frac 1 2 mv^2 + mc^2$ for $v$ << $c$.

You've gone wrong by equating $E$ to just kinetic energy, and then using $E$ equal to just the rest energy $mc^2$.

Comment: You could taylor expand if you want to                                                           not use the slow-motion approximation, (contd